# PayPal Express Checkout - Webhook PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED

Tags: paypal, webhooks, paypal-subscriptions, express-checkout, paypal-webhooks

I was searching a while and also read the paypal docs but I am unable to find an answer to my question. I created a recurring payment with Paypal Express Checkout. Everything is working fine, but now I need to know a little bit more about webhooks.

Assume a user registered and created a recurring subscription. The set-up fee is 0,00€ and the first payment will be in one week. After the first payment, the billing cycle will be every week. Now about my webhook question: I guess I need to use the `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` webhook am I right? As soon as I get paid every week, the `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` webhook will fire for every successfull payment and therefore add a new entry inside my database. Am I right? Or do I need to use another webhook for recurring payments?

Is there someone who uses this webhook in combination of a recurring subscription? Would be great if someone can help me out understanding if `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` is the correct webhook for recurring subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` is sent after every successful billing event for a subscription.

Here is an example timeline of a subscription sale on my website:

2021-07-30 13:17:13.143: `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` - *first payment*

2021-07-30 13:17:10.679: `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED`

2021-07-30 13:16:15.032: `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CREATED` - *this came after the one above, so make sure you can handle that*

2021-08-30 11:13:05.321: `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` with `"state"=>"completed"` - *second recurring payment*

2021-09-08 14:34:44.816: `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` with  `"state"=>"completed","payment_hold_status"=>"RELEASED"` - *this is the release of the second recurring payment*

If the recurring payment fails, you will receive `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.PAYMENT.FAILED`. Paypal retries the payment 3 times. See the attribute `next_payment_retry_time` which is set to null after the 3rd and final failed payment attempt.

You can configure your billing plan to automatically suspend a subscription after x number of failed payments (note: set this to be 1+ because 0 keeps is always active) and/or automatically add the outstanding payments to the next billing cycling.

Screenshot below:

[image: Automatically pause a subscription on a failed payment]

Comment: Thanks for this.  How do you distinguish between a first payment and recurring payment with PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED ?  Thank you.

Comment: There's no way to do this (at least as far as I can see) from the PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED payload. I look at the order in my own database and can see by the order status whether it is the first payment or a recurring payment.

Comment: Thanks so much, I did same before asking question.   Feels like a hack but I could not think of any other way.   Knowing you did same validates what I did too.

Comment: It isn't a hack at all - Paypal sends you the details of the subscriptions and payments separately and you are expected to maintain your own view in order to perform the necessary actions

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you have any choice for which webhook PayPal will send you. I am fighting with this right now because PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED is the one they send me, but it doesn't contain enough data for me to match it up with a customer or a shopping cart. I want them to return CHECKOUT.ORDER.COMPLETED instead, but there doesn't seem to be a way to make that happen.

Comment: You can set `custom_id` and this is then sent with every webhook notification - at least in 2021, perhaps it was different in 2018